# How to "Open Bottom Sheet Dialog" from "Bottom Navigation Bar" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomsheetdialog

I use bottom navbar from "ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar" and i have a "Bottom sheet dialog". I need to open the Bottom Sheet Dialog from one of the menu items on BottomNavBar but i don't know how to implement to my Kotlin Code.

someone please help me.
and thanks for your help

this my XML Code

```
        <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
            android:id="@+id/chipNavBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/dk_purple"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:cnb_iconSize="30dp"
            app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/item_menu"
            app:cnb_radius="20dp"
            app:cnb_unselectedColor="@color/white" />
```